# `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade` show no updates available for months on my computer

Tags: updates

When I try to update my computer, it says no updates are available. This has been going on for months, and I'm scratching my head--there should be security patches at least.

I'm using Ubuntu 12.04 Precise Pangolin.

Answer (score 1):

Ah, I added a few more Ubuntu sources to my `/etc/apt/sources.list`, based on an example `sources.list` for Ubuntu 12.04:

http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=E2B6i8G8

And 100MB of updates suddenly appeared!